# Ranges in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing event handlers in jQuery. I want to use a specific set of keys (eg arrow keys) for a particular action. Is there a shorthand notation for this?

I have this.

```
if(event.keycode == 37 || event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 39)
```

I'm wondering if there are ranges in JavaScript, like (37..40)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the range effect by using the comparison operators, like so:

```
// keep a local reference to avoid consequent requests
var keyCode = event.keyCode;

// check if key code is in range
if(keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40){
  // in range, do something
} else{
  // out of range, do something else
}
```

Comment: @petraszd: _"I'm wondering if there are ranges in JavaScript, like (37..40)"_ How doesn't that include 40?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(event.keycode >= 37 && event.keyCode <= 39)
```

Not much better in my opinion, and if its only a few key's you're after I would just include them all in the if for better code clarity.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
var code = event.keycode;
if (code >= 37 && code < 40) { /* ... */ }
```

Or (not sure about IE):

```
var code = event.keycode;
if ([37, 38, 39].indexOf(code) != 1) { /* ... */ }
```